# Implicit conversion from class to double

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, double, operator-overloading

Is it possible to implicitly convert a given class to a primitive type? Specifically a double.

If I have a class:

```
class Angle
{
    double value;

    Angle(double init_value = 0.0) : value(init_value) {}

    double get_value() const {return (value);}
}
```

Is there anyway that I can call a function, such as std::sin(), and provide an object of class Angle without explicitly getting out the value of angle with each call? For example:

```
Angle theta(180.0);
double result = std::sin(theta);
```

Instead of having to call std::sin via:

```
Angle theta(180.0);
double result = std::sin(theta.get_value());
```

If there is a way of achieving this desired functionality, I'd assume it would be through operator overloading of an assignment operator. Or maybe though defining a move/copy constructor in a clever way?

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: You could make your own sin that takes an `Angle` eg `double sin(Angle a) { return std::sin(a.get_value());}`

Comment: This is what I've been doing so far, but it may become a hassle if it needs to be done for every function which requires a double type conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the class definition you can define a conversion operator. For example

```
class Angle
{
    //...
    operator double() const { return get_value(); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Does this require to call theta(), rather than just theta, to perform conversion to the double type?

Comment: @user7119460 As you wrote in your question you can use it in the following code snippet Angle theta(180.0);
double result = std::sin(theta);

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much.